# UnicodeDecodeError when saving non ascii character to mongo db

Tags: python, unicode, mongodb, mongoengine

Using mongoengine with mongodb
when saving document which has value with non ascii character got UnicodeDecodeError (mongoengine wraps values with `unicode()` call)
what's the way to deal with it?

Comment: What function call causes this exception to be thrown?

Comment: Good tutorial on unicode encoding & decoding in python: http://www.stereoplex.com/blog/python-unicode-and-unicodedecodeerror

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are calling `unicode()` you should provide the encoding your string is encoded in, so that the `unicode()` function knows how to convert the data. For example:

```
v = "myvalüe"
u = unicode(v, 'utf-8')
```